# ¿Como ejecutar el contenido de un método?

Tags: javascript

El objeto tiene un método llamado `restricciones`, como hago para mostrar el `array` `todas`, envés del cuerpo de la función?

**INTENTO 1:**

```js
var Logarithm = {
  forma: "Log a(b)= c",
  traduccion: "a^c = b",
  restricciones: function() {
  todas: ["No existe logaritmo de un nro negativo","a siempre mayor que 0"] 
   },
};
        
for (var i in Logarithm) {
 document.write(i + ": " + Logarithm[i] + "<p>");
}
```

**INTENTO 2:**

```js
var Logarithm = {
  forma: "Log a(b)= c",
  traduccion: "a^c = b",
  todas: "",
  restricciones: function() {
  this.todas =  ["No existe logaritmo de un nro negativo","a siempre mayor que 0"] 
  },
};
    
for (var i in Logarithm) {
  document.write(i + ": " + Logarithm[i] + "<p>");
}
```

Comment: ¿Lo que buscas es que te ponga en la salida `restricciones: {todas:["No existe el logaritmo..."]}`?

Comment: si es una funcion te falta el return

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tienes que ejecutar la función para que se pueda mostrar

```js
var Logarithm = {
      forma: "Log a(b)= c",
      traduccion: "a^c = b",
      todas: "",
      restricciones: function() {
    
      this.todas =  ["No existe logaritmo de un nro negativo","a siempre mayor que 0"];
      return this.todas.toString();
      },
    };
    
for (var i in Logarithm) {
   document.write(i + ": " + ((typeof Logarithm[i] === 'function') ? Logarithm[i]() : Logarithm[i]) + "<p>");
    
}
```

Comment: Exacto lo que quería! gracias